# Order of the Alternating group

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

According to wikipedia

> For n > 1, the group $A_n$ is the commutator subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ with index 2 and has therefore $\frac{n!}{ 2}$ elements.

I have a question about what the index is. Usually it is the number of left cosets, in this case I assume it includes something about a mapping from $S_n$ to {$\pm 1$} instead of the number of left cosets?

I can see that clearly {$\pm1$} has index 2, but $A_n$ is a subgroup that has elements of $S_n$, so i don't see why that would have index 2.
I am also not sure what the "commutator" subgroup is, which might be where the confusion is.

Once we have index 2, I understand that by Lagrange's theorem, the order of $A_n$ is $\dfrac{n!}{ 2}$.

Comment: $A_n$ has [**index**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup) $2$ in $S_n$; $S_n/A_n\cong \{\pm1\}$ has **order** $2$; $A_n$ has two cosets in $S_n,$ itself and one other

Comment: The commutator subgroup is all elements that can be written as $g^{-1}h^{-1} gh$ for any two elements $g$ and $h$ in the group.

Comment: The commutator subgroup is _generated_ by elements of the form $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$. It's generally larger than this set of elements.

Comment: The commutator subgroup is the hard way to get the order of $A_n$. Much less energy is needed to (1) recall the definition of the alternating group as the group of even permutations, (2) show all the odd elements of the symmetric group are of the form $(1\ 2)\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is an even permutation, (3) conclude the alternating group has index two.

Answer (score 1):

As $A_n\le S_n$ is the subgroup consisting of even permutations,  and exactly half the elements of $S_n$ are even, the index is two.

Recall that a permutation is called even if it can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions.   Odd otherwise.

Define $\operatorname {sgn}:S_n\to \Bbb Z_2$ by $\operatorname {sgn}(\pi)=1$ if $\pi$ is odd, and $\operatorname {sgn}(\pi)=0$ if $\pi$ is even.  It  can be shown that $\operatorname {sgn}$ is a surjective homomorphism (one key  is that the parity of a permutation is an invariant).

Now $A_n=\operatorname {ker}(\operatorname {sgn})$.

Thus by the first isomorphism theorem,  $S_n/A_n\cong \Bbb Z_2$.

The claim about the index follows.